# Usage of clickhouse url engine with query string

Tags: clickhouse

As of

https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/special/url/

we can query data from a remote HTTP/HTTPS server.

The problem is I need to pass query string to URL.

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Look https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/table-functions/url

you can use

```
SELECT * FROM url('https://host:port/path?param=value', <format> , 'stucture')
```